The "-" Operator in SQL where condition
I am encountering a rather peculiar syntax in MySQL, specifically the presence of a '-' symbol within the WHERE condition in the following query.
SELECT 
    users.id
FROM
    users
WHERE
    users.account_status >= 3
        AND users.account_status NOT IN (8 , 9)
        AND - users.registration_status = 14
        AND users.id IN (229);

I've researched this syntax in here?
Could it possibly indicate a transformation of the value of the 'registration_status' column into a negative number?

.. AND - users.registration_status = 14 .. is bad practice, this condition is not SARGable. Use .. AND users.registration_status = -14 .. demo

It's the unary minus operator. The following expressions are all equivalent:

- users.registration_status = 14
0 - users.registration_status = 14
users.registration_status = -14

with the latter probably being the most obvious (code clarity is important!)

The following expressions are all equivalent .. logically. But there is a difference on the execution step, in calculational complexity and resources consumption. The latter variant is preferred one.

@Akina I haven't checked nor do I know the details of the MySQL/MariaDB, but I would assume that the query optimizer creates the same query plan for all of them, since they can be statically transformed to a single canonical expression.

I would assume that the query optimizer creates the same query plan for all of them I provide demo fiddle in the comment to the question where you may see the difference in the execution plans. It is correct for both MySQL and MariaDB. You may test the same for another DBMSs..

Yes it is flipping the sign of users.registration_status before comparing it to 14 in your query
